# Changing code to render carriage return and new line characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a text in SQL Server database that has `new line character` and `carriage return character` in it.  When I assign this value into a string variable, I can see these newline and carriage return as show in first screenshot. But when it is rendered these values are not present (as shown in second screenshot).

How can we `render` the newline and carriage return characters with the following code in gridview?

**CODE**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    List<Account> result = new List<Account>();
    string value = DisplayTest("Daily Tax Updates:\r\n");

    Account acc = new Account(){Description = value};
    result.Add(acc);

    grdFinancialAmount.DataSource = result;
    grdFinancialAmount.DataBind();


}

public class Account
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}


private static string DisplayTest(string searchValue)
{
    string test = String.Empty;
    string connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=LibraryReservationSystem;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        string commandText = @"SELECT AccountType,* 
                          FROM Account 
                          WHERE AccountType LIKE @input ESCAPE '\'";
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection))
        {
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@input", "%" + searchValue + "%");

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {

                        test = reader.GetString(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return test;

}
```

**MARKUP**

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdFinancialAmount" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Text">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("Description")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Variable value from Database

[image: Variable value from Database]

Rendered Value

[image: Rendered Value]

Comment: You could try a `String.Replace()` on `\r\n` with `<br/>`.

Comment: put it in a <div></div>

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the `\r\n` with `\\r\\n` should work fine.

I mis-interpreted this, I though you wanted to show `\r\n` instead of the character return but as a comment says, replace with `<br/>`.

```
string.Replace("\r\n", "<br/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rendered value is html. Putting `\r\n` in html might well change the source html, but will have absolutely no effect on what gets rendered.

You can verify this by doing a "view source" on your rendered window.

One approach here would be, before you render, to replace all occurrences of `\r\n` with `<br/>`, a hard line break.

Or you could add a `<p>` tag to the front of your string, and add a `</p>` tag to the end of your string, then replace all `\r\n` occurrences with `</p><p>`, i.e. split it into paragraphs. This is probably the more elegant approach of the two.

There will be other options here too, you just need to be aware that you need to translate your crlf characters into something html can understand.